# Bold selection of a textbox with click of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have this code: https://jsbin.com/hocisirovo/edit?html,css,js,output

With the button, it bolds the entire text in the text box. How can I bold only what I select in the text box? The easy way would be to use execCommand but I cannot use that.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: simple input type `text` is not sufficient for this task, you need other elements like `div`, `span`, etc

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get your question but you could use an editable div to make parts of your text bold.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getSelectionText() {
 var text = "";
 if (window.getSelection) {
  text = window.getSelection().toString();
        }
        return text;
    }
function boldSelected(){
 var textBox = document.getElementById("textbox");
 var text = textBox.innerHTML;
 var boldText = getSelectionText();
 var offset1 = text.indexOf(boldText);
 var offset2 = offset1 + boldText.length;
 var str1 = text.substring(0,offset1);
 var str2 = text.substring(offset2,text.length);
 textBox.innerHTML=str1+"<b>"+boldText+"</b>"+str2;
}
function undoBold(){
 if(document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML == "<b></b>")
 document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML == "";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onkeypress="undoBold()" contentEditable="true" id="textbox" style="width:30%; border:1px solid #0a0a0a;padding:3px;"></div></br>
<button onclick="boldSelected()">Bold</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you so much for this. It helps greatly.

However, for example if I type in "hello hello hello hello" and highlight the last hello, the first hello will be highlighted. Do you know why it may be doing this?

Thanks

Comment: That's because the code searched for the substring "hello" which it finds at index 0. That's a flaw with the code. I'll improve it and post it again